# Video editor only rendering 1 video channel

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

In my video editor project when I go to *Render > Render Animation* the rendered *.mp4* only renders the channel I'm using for audio (2) and the highest numbered channel I'm using for video (12).

From the beginning of the video until the beginning of the video strip in channel 12 the video displays a black screen.

[image]

My settings being:

[image]
[image]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Please make sure that your blend file is included. Upload it via https://blend-exchange.com/ and copy the code here. Thank you!

Comment: @quellenform Just did it, thank you for letting me know.